# Cannot find wrapper assembly for type library "Redemption"

Tags: visual-studio-2010, outlook-redemption

Okay, I am trying to add a .dll file to my application in Visual Studio 2010.  If it is set for 32 bit, everything is fine.  However, once I switch it to 64 bit, the library has a warning on it and wont load.  I'm assuming the error "A single valid machine type compatible with the input type library must be specified" is related to the .dll not loading properly.  It works fine if the application is moved up to .NET4.0 but I need to try and get this to work in .NET2.0.  Any advice you can give on what is causing Visual Studio to not recognize the redemption64.dll would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you project is set to build as "Any CPU", not x86 or x64 when you import the Redemption type library.

Comment: That solved it.  Thank you so much, I was wracking my brain trying to figure out how to get it to work.